# Program to decrypt file for only one process

Tags: filesystems, disk-encryption

I looking for a program to encrypt and decrypt files (better if directory) on fly and for only one process via cli.
In my mind it must work like sudo:
If you run `cat $crypted_file` (also in superuser mode) you see only crypted byte; if you run `program cat $crypted_file` you can read file.
The top would be encrypt entire folder (or partition) which can be read only with `program bash` command.
Exists anything like that?

Comment: [Openssl can do that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056135/how-to-use-openssl-to-encrypt-decrypt-files) You may wrap it on some bash scripts for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A `gpg` solution would be to decrypt a file to standard output, and pipe it to your program. This requires the program to read for `stdin`, which may not be the case. I made an alias for this on my system:

```
$ gpg -q --output -
$ alias gpgcat='gpg -q --output -'
```

Then...

```
$ gpgcat encryptedfile.gpg | ./myprogram
```

From user236012's comment, you could write the following OpenSSL alternative:

```
$ echo "Hello, World!" > secrets.txt
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in secrets.txt -out secrets.txt.enc
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in secrets.txt.enc
Hello, World!
```

You might also want an alias for the last one, since you're interested in decryption:

```
$ alias opensslcat='openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in'
```

(note that this defines cipher and salt options which you might not want to use)

Also remember that many programs accept `-` as a file argument representing standard input. For instance:

```
$ gpgcat MyBigSecret.gpg | gzip - > NoMoreSecret.gz
```

Here, `gzip` got access to the uncrypted version of the file, and you may read the result by decompressing: `gzip -dc NoMoreSecret.gz`.